# Using a full stop after razor code causes 'identifier expected' error in MVC4 but not MVC3

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

`Test.vbhtml`

```
<span>The time is @DateTime.Now.</span>

@Helper Time()
    @<p>The time is @DateTime.Now.</p>
End Helper
```

**Note the full stop (`.`) at the end of the `@DateTime.Now`**

MVC3 accepts `Test.vbhtml`. Both the `<span>` line and the `@Helper` compile.

MVC4 gets a compilation error in the helper only:

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30203: Identifier expected.
```

The `<span>` in MVC4 works but the `@Helper` does not.

A solution is easy enough, such as replacing the full stop with `&#46;`. **But why does this happen?**

Edited for clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the dot placed as such the compiler looks for a property or method name. Do like this instead:

```
@<p>The time is @(DateTime.Now).</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution. Why does it not look for a method name in MVC3 but it does in MVC4?

Comment: Mmm... Not really sure, I didn't even know @DateTime.Now. would work on MVC3. But it could be because the regular expression in MVC3 looks ahead and can know if what comes after the . (dot) is worth using or not. Maybe this introduces an overhead in compilation time and Microsoft decided to remove it to improve performance.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to use @ sign then use as shown below. it solves the problem.
razor tries to look for @sign before rendering so it creates problem.

```
<text>&#64;</text><p>
```

Comment: The `@` is required. It's used to differentiate HTML and VB code. The `@` isn't the problem, the full stop is.